# Can a definable group of definable automorphisms of a field contain the Frobenius automorphism?

Tags: model-theory, fields, automorphism-groups

Let $K$ be an infinite definable field of characteristic $p >0$ in a certain theory $T$ with a definable group of definable automorphisms. Can this group contain the Frobenius automorphism?

Comment: If you can define $K$, then you can define its prime subfield $\mathbb F_p = \{x \in K : x^p = x\}$, which has only the Frobenius = trivial automorphism and so has a defineable group of defineable automorphisms.  Right?  I guess I'm assuming $p$ itself is available as a parameter.  (This comment is from before the word "infinite" was added.)

Comment: Sorry I see only later my error.

Comment: Why not? Consider the two-sorted structure where one sort is the field $K$, the other sort is the full automorphism group $G$, and we have a binary function symbol $a\colon G\times K\to K$ such that $a(\sigma,x) = \sigma(x)$. Then $G$ is a definable group of definable automorphisms of $K$ which contains *every* automorphism, in particular the Frobenius.

Comment: Expanding a bit upon Alex's comment: note that this property (the definable group of automorphism containing the Frobenius) is actually itself definable, unlike the property of being the full automorphism group (which will typically not be true in most models, even if we start with one in which this is true).